# Use of object-acl-expression in s3-outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I want to use object-acl-expression in s3-outbound-gateway as mentioned below configuration
        but, its throwing "Illegal state Exception" due to null value in else section.I dont want to set any other access controll in else section.
        Could you please suggest some solution on this ?.

```
<int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway
        id="id" request-channel="requestChannelId"
        reply-channel="replayChannelId"
        transfer-manager="tm"
        bucket-expression="bucketName" 
        object-acl-expression="headers.S3_FULL_ACCESS_OWNER_ENABLED == 'Y' ? T(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList).BucketOwnerFullControl : null
        key-expression="headers.file_name" 
        command="UPLOAD">
    </int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway>
```

expected : object-acl-expression should be as default provided in the bucket
 Actual : Throwing "Illegal state exception"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current implementation of the `object-acl-expression`. Just because it doesn't support `null` for evaluation result:

```
Object acl = this.objectAclExpression.getValue(this.evaluationContext, requestMessage);
Assert.state(acl instanceof AccessControlList || acl instanceof CannedAccessControlList,
                    "The 'objectAclExpression' ["
                            + this.objectAclExpression.getExpressionString()
                            + "] must evaluate to com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AccessControlList " +
                            "or must evaluate to com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList. " +
                            "Gotten: [" + acl + "]");
```

We can fix this, of course, and you feel free to raise an issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues

Meanwhile as a workaround I see a solution based on the `S3ProgressListener`, similar to what we do internally:

```
progressListener = new S3ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPersistableTransfer(PersistableTransfer persistableTransfer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
                    if (ProgressEventType.TRANSFER_COMPLETED_EVENT.equals(progressEvent.getEventType())) {
                        S3MessageHandler.this.transferManager.getAmazonS3Client().setObjectAcl(theAclRequest);
                    }
                }

            };
```

Only the problem here that you don't have access to the message in that `progressChanged` context... I think this is something we have to fix as well.

Maybe you can just live for now with the `CannedAccessControlList.AuthenticatedRead` instead of `null` ?

Comment: Thank you Artem. I will go for the solution you suggested for time being and i will raise a ticket for the same as well.

Comment: I have raised a issue on the same https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/106

Comment: Good. I’ll fix that tomorrow.